# Transaction id mismatch on thinly provisioned LVM-Volumes

Tags: lvm

I have setup a thinpool with 3 thinly provisioned LVM volumes inside. After increasing the size of those I did run into serious problems and now I would like to remove the thinpool in order to start from scratch.

Unfortunatelly the system (ubuntu 14.04.03) did not let me do that due to mdata and tdata problems. The device seemed also to be active. I then rebooted into CentOS7 live System from USB. This made it possible to delete one of the volumes.

The other two volumes and the thinpool remain problematic and now I do get the following error msg:

lvremove vg0/project1

device-mapper: thin 353:9: unable to switch pool to write mode until repaired
Thin pool transaction_id=4, while expected: 5
Failed to update mythinpool

I tried lvconvert --repair vg0/mythinpool

This told me that volumegroup vg0 has insuficiant space: 1 extends, 5 required.

Unfortunatelly vg0 is the only volume groupe on the system sharing root and all other volumes.

Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance for any help on this topic!